# What is the easiest way to reader entire byteStream/inputStream response into memory in OkHttp?

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, okhttp

Relatively new to both Kotlin and OkHttp. Currently have the following code

```
class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
        val okClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

        val okRequest: Request = Request.Builder().url(request!!.url.toString()).build()

        val response = okClient.newCall(okRequest).execute()

        return WebResourceResponse("", "", response.body!!.byteStream())
        
        // cant call response.close() otherwise the above return object breaks
    }
}
```

Having trouble with trying to call `response.close()` because it breaks my `byteStream()`

What is the easiest way to read the entire contents of the response into an internal byte array/in-memory input stream?

(Before subsequently closing the connection, and passing the in-memory copy of the input stream to the response?)

Comment: Read all in a ByteArrayOutputStream. Then return the byte array.

Comment: The caller can close the stream.

Comment: @blackapps Would you mind putting that into an answer with a code example? I believe it would help all future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try one of these:

response.body().bytes()
response.body().string()

Comment: The object `WebResourceRequest(...)` MUST take an `InputStream`. Neither of your suggestions can be passed into the response.

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up wrapping the results in an `ByteArrayInputStream(...)` call. This solution worked for me.

```
class CustomWebViewClient : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldInterceptRequest(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): WebResourceResponse? {
        val okClient: OkHttpClient = OkHttpClient()

        val okRequest: Request = Request.Builder().url(request!!.url.toString()).build()

        val response = okClient.newCall(okRequest).execute()

        val result = WebResourceResponse("", "", ByteArrayInputStream(response.body!!.bytes()))

        response.close()

        return result
    }
}
```